# Data not getting shown in select box in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a problem where on every click of icon ,we need to show one select box (taken from material ui) and this select has few options inside it .As we click the icon again ,we gain see the select box.The problem statement is something like this .
[link to solution where i render a header instead of select box](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpny3jvy5o)

What I see is that all the three  options inside select box does not displayed ?
Here is the code .

```
includeblocks=()=>{
    const {classes}=this.props;
    let ClassData=[{
        _id:101,title:'Lol1',
        _id:102,title:'Lol2',
        _id:103,title:'Lol3'
    }];


  let formtoinsert=<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
   <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Class</InputLabel>
   <Select
     value={this.state.classselected}
     onChange={this.handleChange4}
     inputProps={{
       name: "classselected",
       id: "age-simple"
     }}
   >
     <MenuItem value="">
     </MenuItem>
     {ClassData.map(item => {
     return(
         <MenuItem value={item._id}>{item.title}</MenuItem>
     );
   })}

   </Select>
 </FormControl>;

  table=[];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.counter; i++) {
       table.push(formtoinsert);
  }
  console.log("table",table);
  return table;
}
```

I render this function in my render as jsx .What is the correct approach and where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that:

1) you have pretty strange ClassData array, it's just array of a single `{_id: 103, title: "Lol3"}` object. Should be something like this:

```
let ClassData = [
 {_id:101,title:'Lol1'},
 {_id:102,title:'Lol2'},
 {_id:103,title:'Lol3'}
];
```

2) are you sure this.state.counter is greater than 0? :)

2.1) you'll get 'Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"' error in console (because of non unique keys)

3) where is table defined? 
should be

`let table=[];`

4) wrap your jsx in formtoinsert into '()' or even wrap as function with current counter step parameter (to fix 2.1 error)

Example code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ybigus/fkxn3wvr/2/

Hope that helps